# Refresh preference fragment on changing list preference

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm designing an application that supports 3 languages. I have added an option to select the language in preference fragment. The locale in the preference fragment will not change immediately after selecting the language from `ListPreference`.
But if I navigate back to `MainActivity` and come back to `SettingsActivity` the locale will be changed in the preference screen as well.

I need a solution to change the locale in the PreferenceFragment as soon as there is a change in the ListPreference value (i.e. when the language is selected.)

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**: 
Now I'm using custom list preferences class `CustListPreference`that extends `ListPreference` and implements `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`

I have defined an OK button in the list preference. Now in the `OnClick` method when ok is pressed I'm updating the configuration using

`getContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);`, but no luck. The view is not getting updated.

Some one please suggest me how to refresh the activity or restart onClick of OK button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart you activity, after changing the locale.

Or Try updating configuration, something like that:

```
public void changeLanguage(Configuration configuration) {
    configuration.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;//or other locale

    Locale.setDefault(configuration.locale);
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, null);
}
```

Comment: @oguzhang: Thanks for the quick response. Can you please let me know how to achieve it on changing the `ListPreference`

Comment: @oguzhang, I have used the above method in PreferenceFragment Class. I'm getting an error like Cannot resolve the method 'getBaseContext()'. What should be done?

Comment: @Swaroop it was just an example, you can change it according to your usage. Try "getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, null);" or "getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, null);"

Comment: @oguzhang: I have updated the question. Please let me know if anything can be done further.